# Managing multiple Bluetooth connections in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Im a newbie here. Im implementing an android Bluetooth project as part of my academics.
I have gone through the Bluetooth chat example provided by Google, but i am stuck at the connection establishment phase.

My project contains a server and multiple clients( less than 7). The client and server need to exchange data. It is my understanding that i need multiple UUID to be able to accept multiple socket connections simultaneously, which is what i want. However what im not able to understand is

1. How to identify at the server, the request coming from each client and send correct responses to each client?
2. Is it Necessary to implement "Connect Thread", "Accept Thread", "Connected Thread" classes as shown in Bluetooth chat example.

Comment: So far i'v been able to establish a connection for a single device. tried to establish multiple connections by starting multiple sockets with different UUID when the code runs.. It starts the sockets successfully.. but whenever a second device tries to establish connection, the first one also loses its connection. Any suggestions on how to get around this problem?